# Big O notation and derivative

Tags: calculus, number-theory, derivatives, asymptotics

Given a function $f(x) = x^2 + g(x)$ such that $g(x) = O(x)$ and that $f'(x)$ is monotonic non-decreasing for all $x \geq x_0$

I need to prove that $g'(x) = O(\sqrt{x})$, and also that without the monotonic condtion such implication is false

For the latter question I have $g(x) = \sin(x^2) = O( x)$ but $g'(x) = 2x \cos(x^2) = O(x)$.

Which means that the solution to the first question $g'(x) = O(\sqrt{x})$ depends on the fact that $f'$ is monotonic but I couldn't prove it. How to prove it then?

Comment: I'd like to clarify something. Does $O(x\sqrt{x})$ imply that $g(x) \geq 0$ for $x \geq 0$? If that's not the case then there exists a counter example. Let $g(x) = - \frac{4}{3} x \sqrt{x}$. Now $f(x)$ has a turning point at $x = 1$ and therefore is not non-decreasing for all $x$.

Comment: Are you sure that $g(x) = O(x \sqrt x)$ and not $g(x) = O(x)$?

Comment: @corner3 the question says that $f'$ is non-decreasing in some interval $[x_0,\infty)$.

Comment: @BartMichels you are right, i will correct it.

Comment: @bjorn93 thanks! I missed that in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Use the mean value theorem.

> The MVT gives, for $x, h > 0$ such that $x-h > x_0$:
>  $$\frac{f(x) - f(x-h)}h \leq f'(x) \leq \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}h$$
>  Plugging in $f(x) = x^2+g(x)$:
>  $$\frac{g(x) - g(x-h) - h^2}h \leq g'(x) \leq \frac{g(x+h) - g(x) + h^2}h $$
>  Now take $h = \sqrt x$ to bound $g'(x)$ from above and below by $O(\sqrt x)$ functions.

Comment: How do we know that $x^{-1/2}(g(x+\sqrt x)-g(x))=O(\sqrt x)?$

Comment: Because $g(x)=O(x)$